# Div Elements Not Showing Properly

Tags: html, css

I have been having this problem for a couple of weeks now. I have this code

```css
div{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px outset black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>testing</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and it is doing this: [image: Weird CSS]

I have looked at tutorials, searched on Stack Overflow, and even when I run it in the code snippet, it works. What am I doing wrong!?!?
Edit: I also wanted to add this image to show you that it works perfectly fine in the code snippet. [image: GoodCSS]

Comment: Is there more to your code? Because clicking on the snippet it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @Mamdlv Nope, that's it. In the snippet it works for me, but it's just when trying it on my local server that it gets ruined.

Comment: have you tried opening it with a different browser ?

Comment: No not yet, I should probably try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening it with a different browser.